# Can I reuse the old dryer wiring for a generator plug? it's missing a ground

Tags: grounding, generator

My generator needs a four wire connection but the dryer plug is only a three wire type. Can I just run a new ground wire along the path of the dryer wires?  I know that electrically it would work but I would like it to pass code also. I already have the interlock in place.

Comment: Have you checked the cable first to see if you need extra ground?  Sometimes they used /3 plus ground but did not use the ground since the dryer had only three prong plug.

Comment: New code allows a ground wire to be added to circuits, like outlets, dryers, but do not know about generator inlet feed.

Comment: So your question is just the code?  You might be able to call your local inspector and ask...

Comment: Your generator needs an *inlet*, not an *outlet*. Plus the generator inlet should be *outside* to avoid the risk of running the generator inside "just for a little while until it stops raining" and killing you with carbon monoxide. So while you *may* be able to reuse some of the wiring (30A is common for dryer and for generator) you can't reuse the receptacle and it probably should be moved (as well as replaced with an inlet).

Comment: I have the right plug and some extra wiring that has three wires plus the ground, 8 gauge I believe. The actual plug will be outside. It is the correct type for generator of my size.

Comment: Op here.  I checked in the dryer cable doesn't have an extra ground.  I'm not doing this job on the cheap it's just expensive to buy 100 ft of 3 + 1 cable in 8 awg so I'd like to reuse what I've got if I can.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can retrofit ground to the existing circuit, and then extend the circuit from there with cable such /3 Romex or SER cable.  You'll need to extend to an **inlet** - it's illegal to use an outlet and a suicide cord. The inlet should be outdoors, every hurricane kills a family who left a door cracked open to let a generator cord through.

If you are too cheap for a proper inlet, don't violate code with a suicide cord - violate code by sticking a box outside and attaching a 4-wire dryer cord to it, with a proper strain relief where it enters the box.

Comment: I have all the proper chords that are specifically for generators. I have the box that will get connected to the outside of the house. I have the conduit to go from the house to the box. I was pretty much ready to start installation when I realized adding a ground this way may not pass code.